# How to get value in dict if dict can change

Tags: python

I have a data where I want to take some data. But i have a problem, that dict can change and have additional field. That field is middle_name. How to take `given_name,familly_name,distributor_id,middle_name,name`. if it is

I tried to do it with `len` of dict, but I have `len` of dict 15. Also I tried to take it with `get('claims')` and take it with massive, but it took all values and that not what i want

```
InfoAboutUser={'distributor_id': '',
 'family_name': '',
 'given_name': '',

 'middle_name': '' 
 'name': ''}


getID=[{
 'claims': [{'claimType': 'given_name',
             'claimValue': 'string1',
             'id': 19052,
             'userId': 'string 0'},
            {'claimType': 'family_name',
             'claimValue': 'string2',
             'id': 19053,
             'userId': 'string 0'},
            {'claimType': 'distributor_id',
             'claimValue': 'string3',
             'id': 19054,
             'userId': 'string 0'},
            {'claimType': 'middle_name',
             'claimValue': 'string4',
             'id': 19055,
             'userId': 'string 0'},
            {'claimType': 'name',
             'claimValue': 'string5',
             'id': 19056,
             'userId': 'string 0'},
            {'claimType': 'vendor_id',
             'claimValue': 'string6',
             'id': 19057,
             'userId': 'string 0'}],
 '}]


distributor_id = getID['claims'][2]['claimValue']
        InfoAboutUser['distributor_id'] = distributor_id
        #print(distributor_id)

        given_name = getID['claims'][0]['claimValue']

        InfoAboutUser['given_name'] = given_name
        #print(given_name)

        family_name = getID['claims'][1]['claimValue']
        InfoAboutUser['family_name'] = family_name
        #print(family_name)

        name = getID['claims'][3]['claimValue']
        InfoAboutUser['name'] = name
        #print(name)
```

I expect the output of

```
{'distributor_id': 'string3',
 'family_name': 'string2',
 'given_name': 'string1',

 'middle_name': 'string4',
 'name': 'string5'}
```

or

```
{'distributor_id': 'string3',
 'family_name': 'string2',
 'given_name': 'string1',

 'middle_name': '' # If it is not available,
 'name': 'string5'}
```

bit the actually output is

```
{'distributor_id': 'string3',
 'family_name': 'string2',
 'given_name': 'string1',

 'middle_name': '' 
 'name': 'string4'
```

Comment: please show us your python code.

Comment: @ Mig B , that all code which i have. And i added dict where i should save date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem about processing your dictionary is, that wrapped an array around it.
To access your date, you have to use the first entry of `getID` with `getID[0]`. Afterwards you can loop through the `claims` entry as shown.

```
datas = {}
for claim in getID[0]['claims']:
    datas[claim['claimType']] = claim['claimValue']

print(datas)
#{'given_name': 'string1', 'family_name': 'string2', 'distributor_id': 'string3', 'middle_name': 'string4', 'name': 'string5', 'vendor_id': 'string6'}
```

If you want to extract explicit, you could define the wanted keys into a list and just write those entries into your datas dictionary.

```
datas = {}
wanted_keys = ["given_name","familly_name","distributor_id","middle_name","name"]
for claim in getID[0]['claims']:
    if claim['claimType'] in wanted_keys:
        datas[claim['claimType']] = claim['claimValue']
print(datas)
#{'given_name': 'string1', 'distributor_id': 'string3', 'middle_name': 'string4', 'name': 'string5'}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem correctly then one of the solution could be to iterate over all of the claims:

```
for claim in getID[0].get('claims'):
  if(claim.get('claimType')) == "middle_name":
    print(claim.get('claimValue'))
```